# Best practices - where to run new gas line?

Tags: basement, pipe, gas

I want to run a gas line from my meter to a grill on a deck I'm building.  Because of various outdoor obstructions, the easiest path is to run the line through my (mostly) unfinished basement.  In this picture we're facing the concrete foundation wall, the gas meter is outside and just to the left; to the right of the picture is the steel I-beam that bisects my house (the joists are 12' long and they overlap on top of the steel beam).  I've put a hanging wall to separate the basement into two halves, the room on the other side of that hanging wall is also unfinished except for the walls.

[image: Joist bay]

Is there a "best practice" for where, within that joist bay, to run the new gas line?  I was thinking that if I run it right next to the joist, it's going to be tricky when I have to drill a hole through the joist block (visible to the right), I could end up running into a nail that holds the block in place.  Is there any reason not to run the new pipe more or less down the middle of the joist bay?  I could put a 2x4 between joists to provide support.

Is there any danger with having those electrical wires right next to the pipe?  Would I need to provide some spacing, or if the wires rested gently on the pipe there would be no danger?

Comment: Regarding hitting any potential nails, a good augur bit can handle small nails and a bimetal holesaw won't have problems with wood or metal.